# Grid with multiple records matchs with the master record being displayed

Tags: asp.net, gridview

## Scenario:-

You have a screen with a master record and a grid with multiple detail records, such as "Order" and "Order Line Items".  The user can "scroll" from one master record to the next, or back again.

## Question:-

How will you guarantee that the detail grid records being displayed always match the master record being displayed.

Comment: provide some more details and possibly code will help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think implementation of cascading dropdown technique may help.